# Is it possible to effectively assign a static IP address to an Azure Web App using NAT?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, vnet

My application is making HTTP requests to a 3rd party API which has an IP whitelist.
Of course, I could add the IP addresses assigned when the Web App is created but test environments are created and destroyed on demand, meaning we need to request an update the whitelist.

My thoughts are to attached the Web App to an existing VNet and assign a NAT to specify the outbound IP. Will that work?

Comment: i have no idea about this topic, but my obvious question is: have you tried it yourself?

Comment: I will work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi thats it. I was missing the **WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL** setting.

Comment: @zXynK  You can send out your answer to the issue, which can help more forum users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official document, the example operation can be completed, `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` needs to be configured, and you need to pay attention to `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` is currently not supported in Windows containers.